# How to set today's date as a default in the input box using of ng-it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to set today's date as a default in the input box using of ng-it?

- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rjRDPTZOAPPG734aAbxB?p=preview)
- I just want to set today's date as a default in input field using of `ng-it`.
- please check my plunker and help us thanks.

**My code :-**

```
    <div ng-app="" ng-init="to='2018-01-24'">

<p>Default date in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="date" ng-model="to"></p>
<p>You wrote: {{ to }}</p>

</div>
```

- In plunker we are expecting second input field value is today's date...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but I think you can not call native JS function/object in ng-init. What you can do is to have a proxy in `$rootScope` (assuming you only have one ng-app):

In your javascript:

```
 angular.module("foo", []).run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {

     $rootScope.date = new Date();
 }]);
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="foo" ng-init="firstname='John'; currentDate=date">
```

Based on the previous javascript, you could directly use the `date` object (as I updated in your Plunker).

I strongly advise to only have one app for one page in AngularJS, as documented, the auto-bootstrapping can only handle one ng-app (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

I think it is a good practice to have all used scope wrapped by a controller.

Here is the partly updated plunker (without the add of a controller):
http://plnkr.co/edit/BLVWN4jHIMwEuZzjA698?p=preview

Comment: thanks for update, but I just want answer like without using of controller and java-script is there any possibility? please help us, thanks, why Because in my project controller part has not updating in server side , if we do work in the html part it would running perfectly , that's why I am expecting answer like ng-it to fix the default value....

Comment: Ok, so can I assume that you can generate the current date from your server? So I guess you can render the current date in the ng-init? If yes, I updated the plunkr. If it is ok for you I will update my answer